# Re-combine key value pairs of objects and nested objects in array to new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Hope you can support on this one.
The purpose is to arrange the data into arrays of objects that a material UI DataGrid can consume.

How can I 'convert' the following json data (loaded from a API endpoint).
array = mainData

```
const mainData = [
  {
    "updated_at": null,
    "created_at": "2021-06-24T15:12:21.195400",
    "table_id": "e7cf7bfd-98ce-4097-85a2-0124aa7a8d76",
    "data": {
      "type": "INTEGER",
      "unique": "False",
      "nullable": "False",
      "primary key": "False",
      "auto increment": "False"
    },
    "name": "Jedi Name",
    "id": "7e3117e7-6484-4895-9362-9d2f34a13e29",
    "column_parent_id": null,
    "position": 1,
    "description": "The name of the Jedi"
  },
  {
    "updated_at": null,
    "created_at": "2021-06-24T15:14:11.264108",
    "table_id": "e7cf7bfd-98ce-4097-85a2-0124aa7a8d76",
    "data": {
      "type": "INTEGER",
      "unique": "False",
      "nullable": "False",
      "primary key": "False",
      "auto increment": "False"
    },
    "name": "event_timestamp",
    "id": "89cfdef5-5401-4f20-bbd9-e023ee8d4d74",
    "column_parent_id": null,
    "position": 3,
    "description": "some description"
  },
  {
    "updated_at": null,
    "created_at": "2021-06-24T15:01:21.873429",
    "table_id": "e7cf7bfd-98ce-4097-85a2-0124aa7a8d76",
    "data": {
      "type": "INTEGER",
      "unique": "False",
      "nullable": "False",
      "primary key": "False",
      "auto increment": "False"
    },
    "name": "event_date",
    "id": "7fab9e69-5fa7-44f8-8a07-0d7638901e99",
    "column_parent_id": null,
    "position": 2,
    "description": "some description."
  }
]
```

Into the following array of objects:

```
const newArray = [
  { id: 1, rowIdentifier: 'type', '7e3117e7-6484-4895-9362-9d2f34a13e29': 'INTEGER', '89cfdef5-5401-4f20-bbd9-e023ee8d4d74': 'INTEGER', '7fab9e69-5fa7-44f8-8a07-0d7638901e99': 'INTEGER' },
  { id: 2, rowIdentifier: 'unique', '7e3117e7-6484-4895-9362-9d2f34a13e29': 'false', '89cfdef5-5401-4f20-bbd9-e023ee8d4d74': 'false', '7fab9e69-5fa7-44f8-8a07-0d7638901e99': 'false' },
  { id: 3, rowIdentifier: 'nullable', '7e3117e7-6484-4895-9362-9d2f34a13e29': 'false', '89cfdef5-5401-4f20-bbd9-e023ee8d4d74': 'false', '7fab9e69-5fa7-44f8-8a07-0d7638901e99': 'false' },
  { id: 4, rowIdentifier: 'primary key', '7e3117e7-6484-4895-9362-9d2f34a13e29': 'false', '89cfdef5-5401-4f20-bbd9-e023ee8d4d74': 'false', '7fab9e69-5fa7-44f8-8a07-0d7638901e99': 'false' },
  { id: 5, rowIdentifier: 'auto increment', '7e3117e7-6484-4895-9362-9d2f34a13e29': 'false', '89cfdef5-5401-4f20-bbd9-e023ee8d4d74': 'false', '7fab9e69-5fa7-44f8-8a07-0d7638901e99': 'false' },
  
];
```

In newArray
id must increment by one for each object in the newArray,
rowIdentifier is a fixed key, the value of this pair is the values from the nested array (data) of this other array where tableData.id = mainData.table_id
array = tableData

```
const tableData = [
  {
    "updated_at": null,
    "created_at": "2021-06-28T10:08:17.194149",
    "data": [
      "type",
      "unique",
      "nullable",
      "primary key",
      "auto increment"
    ],
    "name": "online sales",
    "id": "d4578826-555c-454f-a895-81c851378246",
    "source_id": "865bfe91-375a-43d9-bece-c96c81733469",
    "description": "e-comm sales data from GA"
  },
  {
    "updated_at": null,
    "created_at": "2021-06-22T18:46:16.666728",
    "data": [
      "type",
      "unique",
      "nullable",
      "primary key",
      "auto increment"
    ],
    "name": "Big Query ga_sessions",
    "id": "e7cf7bfd-98ce-4097-85a2-0124aa7a8d76",
    "source_id": "865bfe91-375a-43d9-bece-c96c81733469",
    "description": "Defualt export from Google Analytics 4 to Big Query"
  }
]
```

the nested array (data) can have whatever number of strings. This can change.

newArray continued:
for each id of the parent objects in mainData array the id must be key and the value must be the value of the nested data object of the parent object, and matching the 'rowIdentifier' value. Each object of newArray must have key value pairs for each id of mainData.

It's okay if more intermediate arrays or objects are needed. Please let me know if I can clarify

Comment: Research into Array prototype methods like `map()`. StackOverflow is not a coding service.

Comment: I did for map, for loops, foreach, some, filter, objetcs., and almost any other function related to topics similar to this. I have done several coding attemps. I'm not taking the capabilities of staceoverflow for granted. @funkizer you seem to know the drill. What can I do different to get constructive input on this matter?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const mainData = [
  {
    "updated_at": null,
    "created_at": "2021-06-24T15:12:21.195400",
    "table_id": "e7cf7bfd-98ce-4097-85a2-0124aa7a8d76",
    "data": [
      "type",
      "unique",
      "nullable",
      "primary key",
      "auto increment"
    ],
    "name": "Jedi Name",
    "id": "7e3117e7-6484-4895-9362-9d2f34a13e29",
    "column_parent_id": null,
    "position": 1,
    "description": "The name of the Jedi"
  },
  {
    "updated_at": null,
    "created_at": "2021-06-24T15:14:11.264108",
    "table_id": "e7cf7bfd-98ce-4097-85a2-0124aa7a8d76",
    "data": [
      "type",
      "unique",
      "nullable",
      "primary key",
      "auto increment"
    ],
    "name": "event_timestamp",
    "id": "89cfdef5-5401-4f20-bbd9-e023ee8d4d74",
    "column_parent_id": null,
    "position": 3,
    "description": "some description"
  },
  {
    "updated_at": null,
    "created_at": "2021-06-24T15:01:21.873429",
    "table_id": "e7cf7bfd-98ce-4097-85a2-0124aa7a8d76",
    "data": [
      "type",
      "unique",
      "nullable",
      "primary key",
      "auto increment"
    ],
    "name": "event_date",
    "id": "7fab9e69-5fa7-44f8-8a07-0d7638901e99",
    "column_parent_id": null,
    "position": 2,
    "description": "some description."
  }
]

const newArray = mainData.map((key, index) => {
  return {
    id: index+1,
    rowIdentifier: key.data[index],
    "7e3117e7-6484-4895-9362-9d2f34a13e29": key.id === "7e3117e7-6484-4895-9362-9d2f34a13e29" ? 'INTEGER': 'false',
    "89cfdef5-5401-4f20-bbd9-e023ee8d4d74": key.id === "89cfdef5-5401-4f20-bbd9-e023ee8d4d74" ? 'INTEGER': 'false',
    "7fab9e69-5fa7-44f8-8a07-0d7638901e99": key.id === "7fab9e69-5fa7-44f8-8a07-0d7638901e99" ? 'INTEGER': 'false',
  };
});

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: Thanks @mamunur rashid, sorry if this was not clear; The ids cant be hardcoded (actually nothing can be hardcoded), since the mainData can have other ids, and the values of the value pair of the nested object can change as well